# Unable to run Selenium tests (java) from the command line

Tags: java, command-line, selenium

I am using Selenium to do tests on some html. I was using java under Eclipse and run test by Junit. And everything was fine. But I got problems when I started use command line (javac/java at Dos prompt) to compile/run the test.
  For this java project, I have a bunch of classes, each one represents one test while each each class sits in its own java file. And All these files are under one package/folder called "testSuite". Each test file will import a bunch of jar files. And they also import Global class from another 
   The problems, the compile was ok. but I make it run. I compiled global.java first then compiled `PolicyFilter.java` and then try to run the class, below is what I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: \testsuite\PolicyFilter (wrong name: testSuite/PolicyFilter)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `java -cp requiredClassfiles/folders/jars classToExecute`.

I hope you have Selenium RC Jar available and started it using command `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version-number>.jar`.

Comment: Hi, yes I went into the folder that has the class file and tried to use the format above. but it gives me "Could not find or load main class PolicyFilter".

Comment: The command I used: C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\java -classpath "C:\Users\Charlie Zeng\workspace\HelloWorld\src";"C:\Users\Charlie Zeng\Desktop\pro\jars\commons-net-3.1.jar";"C:\Users\Charlie Zeng\Desktop\pro\jars\junit-4.10.jar";"C:\Users\Charlie Zeng\Desktop\pro\jars\selenium-server.jar";"C:\Users\Charlie Zeng\Desktop\pro\jars\selenium-java-2.24.1.jar";"C:\Users\Charlie Zeng\Desktop\pro\jars\selenium-java-2.24.1-srcs.jar";"C:\Users\Charlie Zeng\Desktop\pro\jars\guava-13.0.1.jar" PolicyFilter                   But the class file is right in the current folder.

Comment: I hope you have `main` method created in your `PolicyFilter`. If not, are you extending it from `SeleneseTestCase` or JUnit `TestCase`?

Comment: I think I got your problem. Before running the `PolicyFilter`, run `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.` on the command prompt to include your current directory in the classpath. Run your testcase from parent folder of `testsuite` as `java -classpath yourjars testsuite.PolicyFilter`. Please note: you need to use you class name with the package i.e. `testsuite.PolicyFilter`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I set the classpath to bin folder,library folder(contains all the java file included in PolicyFilter) and src folder as follow. But when I run the java, still got the problem.   (set classpath=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\HelloWorld\src\libraries;C:\HelloWorld\src\testSuite;C:\HelloWorld\jar;C:\HelloWorld\src)  run command: java testsuite.Policyfilter  And I think it found the Policyfilter class. Because when I used another random class name such as PolicyF, it told me could not find or load main class...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you put the annotation @Test on the test, clean the folder target in project folder and then restart the eclipse.
Hope it works :))

Comment: Thanks, But @Test actually was located right before the class. And Now when I run it, it didn't give me error message above, instead it gave me:Error:                                                    Main method not found in class testSuite.PolicyFilter, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)